# jqTable Data Doesn't Show on Deployed website (Azure)

Tags: jquery, .net, azure, deployment

I just desployed a MVC .Net web app on Azure. It works correctly except one table that doesn't show the data, just the empty table. (On localhost it works)

I've deployed this site before and that table just worked fine.. It's a school project and i'm newbie so i don't even know where to search the error.... :S

- I don't have any .js Errors on console (it's a Jquery Table) // Just one about the font but i changed it to Arial and it doesn't changed anything
- jQuery table just get empty data
- In the console NetWork Section I can see the call to the Controller method
- I have a table with the same structure and it works great !!
- The SAME table worked before :S

I think nobody will enter since it is a random web but the URL is: http://letsagree.azurewebsites.net/  , if it can help to find the error.

USER: Admin2
Password: 123456

the page that loads (http://letsagree.azurewebsites.net/Events/MyEvents) should get rows of data, since on localhost it does (with same data). Obviously I proved another users (a lot of them, even new ones), i really know its the same ID and that kinds of stuff..

I don't even know what code should I share, since on localhost it works great.

[image: letsCry]

I recall its a school project so don't judge other stuff :P im working on it. I'm really lost about this problem, like I said before, I don't event know where to look for the problem ..

Thanks.

Comment: The login you provided for your site doesn't work

Comment: sorry its:  admin2  / 123456    without caps

Comment: If you check the console you can see that the call to `/EventsList` is returning no data, just `{}`. You need to check why thats happening in your server side code

Comment: Yes I Know (it's the only conclusion i got), But that method works fine on server, and another similar method  (( http://letsagree.azurewebsites.net/Users/Index  )) works fine on the web.

What do i have to check? Or maybe the question is How.. I'm kind of lost. Thank you for helping btw.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rory McCrossan mentioned, /EventsList returned no data is the reason.  To further debug your issue. I suggest you use Remote Debug feature which provided by Azure Web App. It provides a way to troubleshoot is to run in debug mode remotely if you can't re-create the error locally.

Firstly, you need to enable Remote Debug feature on Azure portal.

[image]

Step 2, We need to re-deploy our web application using Debug configuration.

[image]

Step 3, In Server Explorer, right-click your web app, and then click Attach Debugger. The browser automatically opens to your home page running in Azure. You might have to wait 20 seconds or so while Azure sets up the server for debugging. This delay only happens the first time you run in debug mode on a web app. Subsequent times within the next 48 hours when you start debugging again there won't be a delay.

[image]

After that, you could add a breakpoint in **EventsList method** to check whether it return empty data.